# Limit width of flex item regardless of content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having a hard time explaining my problem, have a look

```css
body { width: 200px }

.a {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
}

.b {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class=a>
  <div class=b>
    <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
  </div>
  <button>
    click
  </button>
</div>
```

What I need is

```css
body { width: 200px }

.a {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
}

.b {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class=a>
  <div class=b>
    <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
  </div>
  <button>
    click
  </button>
</div>
```

Basically cut off the text no matter how long it is and keep it on 1 line. I just can't wrap my head around what I'm messing up... I tried overflow, text-overflow, word-wrap, word-break, white-space - no luck.

Comment: Use `white-space:nowrap;` to keep text in one line when there are spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this occur is based on the fact that flex row item's `min-width` defaults to `auto`.

This mean that it can be smaller than its content, hence the content in `a` will overflow its parent, and with that also push the `button` along with it.

The solution is to either set `min-width` to `0`, or use `overflow` with a value other than `visible`.

In this case the `overflow` will work better, as seen in below sample, as when using `min-width` the overflowed text will be visible.

Stack snippet

```css
body { width: 200px }

.a {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
}

.b {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}

.b2 {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class=a>
  <div class=b>
    <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
  </div>
  <button>
    click
  </button>
</div>

<div class=a>
  <div class=b2>
    <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
  </div>
  <button>
    click
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a max-width and an overflow-hidden in the B element.

```
body { width: 200px }

.a {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
}

.b {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can add another element and a max-height to item b so that horizontal scrolling is hidden and all text can be selected.

https://jsfiddle.net/pk7etoka/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

```css
body { width: 200px }

.a {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: flex;
}

.b {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-x:auto;
  max-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class=a>
  <div class=b>
    <span>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
  </div>
  <button>
    click
  </button>
</div>
```

You can also use the other overflow methods like overflow:hidden/scroll as per your requirement.